# Generating Pythagorean triples using reduced fractions

Tags: pythagorean-triples

I know that this question has answers here, but I'm looking for a way to make the following argument work.

---

Let $(a,b,c)$ be a primitive Pythagorean triple with $a$ even. The goal is to prove that we find coprime integers $x>y>0$ with different parity such that
$$a=2xy,\quad b=x^2-y^2,\quad c=x^2+y^2.$$

*Those are the equalities that we want to prove, we cannot use them to answer my question!*

The idea goes like this: We have $\frac{c+b}{a}=\frac{a}{c-b}$, and we may write this as a reduced fraction $\frac xy$. Surely $x>y>0$ and $x,y$ are coprime by construction. It can now easily be seen that
$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{2xy}=\frac ca,\quad \frac{x^2-y^2}{2xy}=\frac ba.$$

If $x$ and $y$ now have different parity, all $4$ fractions above are reduced, and we can conclude.

Surely, $x$ and $y$ are not both even by assumption, but why can they not both be odd?

Comment: $a,b$ can't both be odd, so we have one of them even, one of them odd and then $c$ must be odd. Choose $b$ to be the odd one, so that $c-b$ is even, which implies that $y$ is even (and therefore $x$ is odd).

Comment: @lulu From where do you get that $y$ is even? Don't you also use the equalities we want to prove...?

Comment: Well, no...but I think I made a different mistake.  Since $a$ and $c-b$ are both even it is, a priori possible that the factors of $2$ cancel in the fraction $\frac a{c-b}$.  For that matter, we could have chosen $b$ to be the even one, in which case $c-b$ and $a$ are both odd, so both $x,y$ would be odd.  So something seems off.

Comment: I posted more details below, under the assumption that we chose $b$ to be the odd one of $a,b$.

Comment: It works if side-A is odd too, e.g. 
$\dfrac{17+8}{15}=\dfrac{25}{15}
=\dfrac{15}{17-8}=\dfrac{15}{9}
=\dfrac{5}{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that one of $a,b$ is odd and the other even.  Let us assume that $b$ is odd, so that $c-b$ is even.  (if, instead, you chose $b$ to be the even one, it would not be true that one of $x,y$ was even).

Now, say $x,y$ were both odd.  It would follow that the numerator $x^2-y^2$ was a multiple of $4$.  But of course $2xy$ would not be a multiple of $4$.  But this would force $b$ to be even, despite the fact that we assumed it to be odd.  Thus it can not be the case that $x,y$ are both odd.

Comment: It's fine, one of my assumptions is that $a$ is even!

Comment: Oh, yes. You did say that.  That makes the argument complete.